# Remove space blank in right side

Tags: border

I'm wanting to eliminate the space between the figure and the edge this is my code, 
or how do I eliminate the space?

How do I eliminate the space on the right side?

```
    \documentclass[a0paper,portrait]{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{copyrightbox} 
\usepackage{float}


\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\CRB@setcopyrightfont}{%
    \footnotesize     %footnotesize  normalsize
    \color{black}   % <--- you can select black because
                }
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\title{Test}

\begin{figure}[H]
            \centering
            \caption{Proceso }
            \label{normalizacionFiguraCopia} 
            \copyrightbox[b]{\begin{tcolorbox}[
  enhanced,clip upper,%<------------
  colframe=gray,colback=white,boxrule=2pt,arc=10pt,
  boxsep=0pt,left=0pt,right=0pt,top=0pt,bottom=0pt]

  \includegraphics[scale=0.8]{example-image}
  \end{tcolorbox}}
{source: asd }
        \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**if i use \frame how can I round the corners? and swell the edge line?**

```
\begin{figure}[H]
            \centering
            \caption{Process}
            \label{copia} 
            \copyrightbox[b]{\frame{

  \includegraphics[scale=0.8]{example-image}}}

{source: asd }
        \end{figure}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your box is just wider than the image. Here is one possible way to set the width appropriately.

```
\documentclass[a0paper,portrait]{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{copyrightbox} 
\usepackage{float}


\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\CRB@setcopyrightfont}{%
    \footnotesize     %footnotesize  normalsize
    \color{black}   % <--- you can select black because
                }
\makeatother

\newsavebox\mybox
\newlength\mywd
\sbox\mybox{\includegraphics[scale=0.8]{example-image}}
\mywd=\wd\mybox
\begin{document}
\title{Test}

\begin{figure}[H]
             \centering
             \caption{Proceso}
             \label{normalizacionFiguraCopia} 
             \copyrightbox[b]{
             \begin{tcolorbox}[width=\mywd,
   enhanced,clip upper,%<------------
   colframe=gray,colback=white,boxrule=2pt,arc=10pt,
   boxsep=0pt,left=0pt,right=0pt,top=0pt,bottom=0pt]
   \includegraphics[scale=0.8]{example-image}
   \end{tcolorbox}}{source: asd }
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can, of course, pack this into a macro.

```
\documentclass[a0paper,portrait]{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{copyrightbox} 
\usepackage{float}


\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\CRB@setcopyrightfont}{%
    \footnotesize     %footnotesize  normalsize
    \color{black}   % <--- you can select black because
                }
\makeatother

\newsavebox\mybox
\newlength\mywd
\newcommand{\TightColorbox}[2][]{%
\savebox\mybox{#2}%
\mywd=\wd\mybox%
\begin{tcolorbox}[width=\mywd,
   enhanced,clip upper,%<------------
   colframe=gray,colback=white,boxrule=2pt,arc=10pt,
   boxsep=0pt,left=0pt,right=0pt,top=0pt,bottom=0pt,#1]
   #2
   \end{tcolorbox}
}   
\begin{document}
\title{Test}
\begin{figure}[H]
             \centering
             \caption{Proceso}
             \label{normalizacionFiguraCopia} 
             \copyrightbox[b]{\TightColorbox{\includegraphics[scale=0.8]{example-image}}
            }{source: asd }
\end{figure}
\end{document}\documentclass[a0paper,portrait]{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{copyrightbox} 
\usepackage{float}


\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\CRB@setcopyrightfont}{%
    \footnotesize     %footnotesize  normalsize
    \color{black}   % <--- you can select black because
                }
\makeatother

\newlength\mywd
\newcommand{\TightColorbox}[2][]{%
\settowidth\mywd{#2}%
\begin{tcolorbox}[width=\mywd,
   enhanced,clip upper,%<------------
   colframe=gray,colback=white,boxrule=2pt,arc=10pt,
   boxsep=0pt,left=0pt,right=0pt,top=0pt,bottom=0pt,#1]
   #2
   \end{tcolorbox}
}   
\begin{document}
\title{Test}
\begin{figure}[H]
             \centering
             \caption{Proceso}
             \label{normalizacionFiguraCopia} 
             \copyrightbox[b]{\TightColorbox{\includegraphics[scale=0.8]{example-image}}
            }{source: asd }
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I would not be surprised if there was an option of `tcolorbox` that achieves the same.

Comment: but i need copyright to source below

Comment: i edit my MWE with source, see please

Comment: Will this solution work for any figure?

Comment: @hubman Yes, as long as you use it also in `\sbox\mybox{\includegraphics[scale=0.8]{example-image}}`. One could just write a quick macro that does all these things.